# Can't move(restore) or delete folder in trash

Tags: command-line, permissions, nautilus, delete, trash

Right now there is a folder called 'Pasta sem nome' (which translates to untitled folder) in trash. 
When I try to delete it or move it I get a message saying I don't have enough permissions.
The owner of Trash is me and not `root` so the commands

```
sudo chown -R "$USER" ~/.local/share/Trash
sudo rm -rf ~/.local/share/Trash/*
```

dont work.

Can't find the answer elsewhere. Any suggestions?

EDIT: Can't test answers until 23/11. Sorry for wasting your time. Please don't close this answer.

Comment: What is the output of `ls -ld Trash`? Are you having write permissions for Trash folder?

Answer (score 0):

See what:

```
lsof | grep Pasta
```

says. It looks to me like some process still has a grip on the file.